# Bulb Flow: How to get a range of vertices?

Tags: python, bulbs

I am trying to find out how is it possible to get a range of vertices from a graph, I am aware that this can be done in gremlin using

```
     gremlin> g.V.range(0,9)
```

But how can this be done using bulb flow model api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can execute a one line Gremlin...

```
>>> from bulbs.rexster import Graph
>>> g = Graph()                                 # create the Graph object
>>> script = "g.V.range(start,end)"             # set a one line script
>>> params = dict(start=0, end=9)               # put function params in dict
>>> vertices = g.gremlin.query(script, params)  # execute the script in DB
```

See http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/

Comment: I am using "from bulbs.titan import Graph" and after following these steps my Vertices look like this...What it the proper way to query the actual value from these URLs

https://gist.github.com/shehaaz/63bdc5d2fb19b69858a0

Thank you! Good work on Bulbs!

Comment: The URL is just the string `repr` displayed by `print` (the actual vertex values are in the `list`). To get at the actual values, you can either iterate through the `iterator`: `for vertex in vertices: print type(vertex) + vertex.data()` or you can convert the `iterator` to a `list` like you've done and access the `list` values by index: `vertices = list(vertices); vertex = vertices[0]; print type(vertex) + vertex.data()`.

Comment: Thank you! wow Python works like magic! :) 
`for vertex in vertices: print vertex.data()`